# Шифр, не чувствительный к последовательности символов

Tags: криптография, шифрование

Из чистого любопытства возник вопрос: существует ли шифр, не чувствительный к последовательности символов? То есть, я шифрую им какое-то сообщение, на выходе получаю символы, перемешиваю их, и затем сообщение все равно можно восстановить.

Comment: На коротких сообщениях это возможно - когда символ кодирует и зашифрованный символ, и его место. В случае 4-байтовой кодировки шифрованного текста при исходном тексте в двухбайтовой кодировке это возможно аж с текстами в 64 кбайт...

Comment: Любопытно, для чего это вам? И что вы понимаете под перемешиванием?

Comment: Всё можно. Объём информации предоставленный **x** байтами но с возможностью перестановки уменьшается очень быстро. Количество информации равно `C[x,255+x]`, длина в байтах `Log[256,C[x,255+x]]`. При предоставленной информации в 1024 байта это превратится в 500 Гигабайт.